# Qt applications rendering glyphs instead of text for a few character combinations

Tags: qt, fonts, text-rendering

I've had this annoying issue where in QT applications (only) certain character combinations are rendered as glyphs instead of the characters. For example `fi` is always rendered as a telephone, `ff` is rendered as two right chevrons. For example:

[image]

My `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf` is included below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <!--Global settings-->
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
      <!--Values: hintnone, hintslight, hintmedium, hintfull-->
      <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
    <!--Subpixel rendering: pixel alignment-->
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign">
      <const>rgb</const>
    </edit>
    <edit name="dpi" mode="assign">
      <double>96</double>
      <!-- <double>144</double> -->
    </edit>
  </match>

  <!--Change monospace font globally-->
  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family" qual="any">
      <string>monospace</string>
    </test>
    <edit binding="strong" mode="prepend" name="family">
      <string>UbuntuMono</string>
    </edit>
  </match>

  <alias>
    <family>Century</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Ubuntu Nerd Font Propo</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>

  <!--Change serif font globally-->
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>NotoSerif Nerd Font Propo</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>

  <!--Change sans-serif font globally-->
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Ubuntu Nerd Font Propo</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>

  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>sans-serif</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Ubuntu Nerd Font Propo</string>
    </edit>
  </match>

  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>serif</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>NotoSerif Nerd Font Propo</string>
    </edit>
  </match>

  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>Apple Color Emoji</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Apple Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
  </match>

  <!-- Disable bitmap fonts to work around https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/2861 -->
  <selectfont><rejectfont><pattern>
    <patelt name="scalable"><bool>false</bool></patelt>
  </pattern></rejectfont></selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

The screenshot example above seems to be a sans-serif font, so for example, here's my `fc-match --verbose sans` output below:

```
Pattern has 42 elts (size 48)
    family: "Ubuntu Nerd Font Propo"(s)
    familylang: "en"(s)
    style: "Regular"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s)
    fullname: "Ubuntu Nerd Font Propo"(w)
    fullnamelang: "en"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 80(f)(s)
    width: 100(f)(s)
    size: 12(f)(s)
    pixelsize: 12.5(f)(s)
    foundry: "DAMA"(s)
    antialias: True(w)
    hintstyle: 1(i)(w)
    hinting: True(w)
    verticallayout: False(s)
    autohint: True(w)
    globaladvance: True(s)
    file: "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/UbuntuNerdFontPropo-Regular.ttf"(s)
    index: 0(i)(w)
    outline: True(s)
    scalable: True(s)
    dpi: 96(f)(w)
    rgba: 1(i)(w)
    scale: 1(f)(s)
    charset: 
    0000: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 7fffffff 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0001: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0002: ffffffff ffffffff 0000ffff 00000000 00040000 10000000 3f0002c0 00000000
    0003: 00020000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffd770 fffffffb 00007fff 00000000
    0004: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 003c000c fffffc00 ffffffff ffffffff 03ffffff
    001e: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000003f 00000000 00000000 000c0000
    001f: 3f3fffff ffffffff aaff3f3f 3fffffff ffffffff ffdfffff efcfffdf 7fdcffff
    0020: 77380000 06010047 00000010 03f10000 000003ff 02105000 00000000 00000000
    0021: 00480000 00004044 7ff80000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0022: 46268044 00000800 00000100 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0023: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 78000000
    0025: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000400 00000000
    0026: 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000020 00000000 00000002 00000000 00000000
    0027: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0003f000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    002b: 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00e0: 000007ff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffff000f 0017f5ff 80000000
    00e2: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 000003ff 00000000 00000000
    00e3: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 0000000f
    00e5: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 fc000000
    00e6: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 00003fff 00000000 00000000
    00e7: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 0000003f 00000000
    00ea: 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffff9dff ffffffff fffff2ff ffffffff
    00eb: fffffbff ffffffff ffff7fff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 00000fff
    00ef: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 20000000
    00f0: 7fff7fff 7ffffffe 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 00077fff 7fff7fff ffff7fff
    00f1: 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff
    00f2: 7fff7fff 7ffffffe 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 7fff7fff 00000001
    00f3: ffffffff 0000ffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00f4: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00f5: ffffffff 000fffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00f8: 3fffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    00fb: 0000001f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0f00: fffffffe ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f01: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f02: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f03: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f04: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f05: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f06: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f07: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f08: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f09: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f0a: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f0b: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f0c: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f0d: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f0e: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f0f: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f10: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f11: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f12: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f13: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f14: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f15: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f16: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f17: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f18: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f19: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0f1a: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 0001ffff
(s)
    lang: aa|ab|af|av|ay|ba|be|bg|bi|br|bs|bua|ca|ce|ch|chm|co|cs|cv|cy|da|de|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fo|fr|fur|fy|gd|gl|gv|ho|hr|hu|ia|id|ie|ik|io|is|it|kaa|ki|kk|kl|kum|kv|kw|ky|la|lb|lez|lt|lv|mg|mh|mk|mo|mt|nb|nds|nl|nn|no|nr|nso|ny|oc|om|os|pl|pt|rm|ro|ru|sah|sco|se|sel|sh|sk|sl|sma|smj|smn|sms|so|sq|sr|ss|st|sv|sw|tg|tk|tl|tn|tr|ts|tt|tyv|uk|uz|vo|vot|wa|wen|wo|xh|yap|zu|an|crh|csb|fil|hsb|ht|jv|kj|kr|ku-tr|kwm|lg|li|mn-mn|ms|na|ng|pap-an|pap-aw|rn|rw|sc|sg|sn|su|ty|za(s)
    fontversion: 54394(i)(s)
    capability: "otlayout:cyrl otlayout:grek otlayout:latn"(w)
    fontformat: "TrueType"(s)
    embeddedbitmap: True(s)
    decorative: False(s)
    lcdfilter: 1(i)(w)
    namelang: "en"(s)
    prgname: "fc-match"(s)
    postscriptname: "UbuntuNFP"(s)
    color: False(s)
    symbol: False(s)
    variable: False(s)
    fonthashint: True(s)
    order: 0(i)(s)
    desktop: "Hyprland"(s)
```

Any other output I can provide to help debug this? I've tried all sorts of `fonts.conf` options, but nothing seems to have helped here. Any idea whats going on here or what I can do to continue debugging? My google-fu is running out haha